# Firebase cloud function with cron-job what happens if connection is closed while executing something

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I want to know what happens if connection becomes nothing while executing some tasks for a Cloud Function.

cron-job.org says this:

> You should design your scripts in a way that they send as little data as possible, ideally just a short status message at the end of the execution, e.g. "OK" — or simply nothing. In case your script is written in PHP and needs more than 30 seconds of run-time, you can use the following trick to let it continue to execute in the background: Use the PHP function ignore_user_abort(true) to tell PHP to continue the script execution after disconnection.

Let's say doing task like query through database with certain condition and delete matched data.
If there are too many data and not finish execution of the task within 30 seconds, what will happen?

Comment: It should be possible to get this situation a fairly simple `setTimeout()` call in the functions. Can you give it a try and see what happens?

Comment: You should be able to simulate what happens when cron-job.org closes the connect by using curl to access the url on the command line, and terminating it early with ctrl-c.  Or access the URL in your browser, and cancel the load.  You can observe what Cloud Functions does in that case.

Comment: Sorry for late reply guys. I just tried that and Cloud Function didn't complete the task. So I'm going to take different approach. Thank you!